# How to loop within a certain range, and restart the loop till the beginning of that range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have the following list:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

i would like to start the loop printing letter 'd', followed by letter 'e' and then continue with the first letter of the list (letter 'a'), and so on and stop at letter 'c'.

This would be the desired output:

```
d
e
a
b
c
```

How can i perform this loop?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can use a simple loop to solve it and what's stopping you in solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that :

```
[liste[x] for x in range(-2,3)]
```

where `liste=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

Comment: Or more general: `[lst[i] for i in range(start - len(lst), start)]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @lauriane.g I know the question may be kind of stupid, but i wasn't clear for me how to di. I didn't know we can give the loop negative starting point :)